# 'Permission denied' to the user who owns the directory

Tags: permissions, mount

I have a USB hard disk on my machine with an ext4 filesystem mounted to `/mnt/data`.
There is a directory `arm` on that disk which belongs to the user "arm".

```
root@adler:~# ll /mnt/data/
total 28
drwxrwx--- 4 root     root      4096 Jul  6 16:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root     root      4096 Jul  6 16:27 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 arm      arm       4096 Jul  6 16:52 arm/
drwx------ 2 www-data www-data 16384 Feb  2 16:24 lost+found/
root@adler:~# ll /mnt/data/arm
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 arm  arm  4096 Jul  6 16:52 ./
drwxrwx--- 4 root root 4096 Jul  6 16:52 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 arm  arm  4096 Jul  6 16:52 music/
```

But user "arm" cannot access this directory:

```
arm@adler:~$ ll /mnt/data/arm
ls: cannot access '/mnt/data/arm': Permission denied
arm@adler:~$ ll /mnt/data/arm/music/
ls: cannot access '/mnt/data/arm/music/': Permission denied
arm@adler:~$ touch /mnt/data/arm/test.txt
touch: cannot touch '/mnt/data/arm/test.txt': Permission denied
```

This is the related line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=2145... /mnt/data ext4 rw,noatime 0 2
```

I'm totally stuck! Any ideas where I could look for the solution?

Comment: why not `UUID=2145... /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 2`? Is there a specific reason to use `rw,noatime`? And also `chmod 777 /mnt/data` to make it accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

arm needs permissions on the parent, too. Try e.g.

```
chmod 775 /mnt/data
```

which gives arm (and anybody else) read- and execute permissons on /mnt/data. Note that for directories execute permission means permission to enter the directory.